# Looping through a all items in a field and updating another field using VBA in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two fields, one is just the number of the other one, e.g. Field 1 = "12AB" and Field 2 is "12".  I'm trying to make Field 2 auto-update but I'm not sure how.

I'm trying to get:

```
ClassName ClassYear
12AB      12
13BU      13
15BE      15
```

But instead the whole fields update to the number in the last one:

```
ClassName ClassYear
12AB      15
13BU      15
15BE      15
```

The code I currently have is

```
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("MasterTable")

  With rst
  Do Until .EOF
    .Edit
    If (Left(ClassName.Text, 1) = "1") Then
      !ClassYear = Left(ClassName.Text, 2)
    Else
      !ClassYear = Left(ClassName.Text, 1)
    End If
    .Update
    .MoveNext
  Loop

  .Close
  End With
```

Help is much appreciated!  Thank you :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `!ClassName`?

Comment: Nope, I want the ClassYear to update depending on what the ClassName is.

Comment: But `ClassName` does not refer to anything, if you mean the *field* the exclamation point is required, IMHO.

Comment: ClassName refers to the control on the form currently open, ClassName.Text gets the text from that control.

Comment: Oh, OK. Better use `Me.ClassName` to make that clear. :) Do you have an `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in your code? If yes, get rid of it for debugging.

Comment: Changed to !ClassName, realised I was wrong.  Although now the program crashes :/

Comment: Please post your changed code as an edit to your original post.

Comment: I think you will find running SQL through VBA is the fastest way to perform this kind of update. It is quite a common thing to do.

Comment: (See your other answer, got it working now. Thanks :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something on the lines of:

```
 sSQL = "UPDATE MasterTable SET ClassYear=Left(ClassName,2) " _
      & "WHERE Left(ClassName,1)='1'"
 CurrentDB.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError

 sSQL = "UPDATE MasterTable SET ClassYear=Left(ClassName,1) " _
      & "WHERE Left(ClassName,1)<>'1'"
 CurrentDB.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: I can't use an SQL query as the form already has the database open, Access wont let me update it via any other way as the database is already in use.

Comment: Not if ClassName refers to a form control, which it apparently does.

Comment: But !ClassYear is in the database and that's what I'm trying to update.

Comment: Are you sure? I have just tested with a table bound to a form and it updates without any problem.

Comment: Ah, I had something extra in there that was breaking it.  This works!  Thanks a lot Remou :)

Comment: There is no reason you should be prevented from running a SQL UPDATE that edits tables you have open in forms as long as there are no unsaved edits in any of those forms. You can save data in the current form with Me.Dirty = False or in any other form with Forms!FormName.Dirty = False. In a subform it would be Me!MySubform.Form.Dirty = False.